# how to run portions of bash script in parallel

Tags: multithreading, bash, for-loop

I am running a bash script consisting of two rather intensive loops that run in sequence (the first loop runs followed by the second). This is quite time consuming and I was wondering if there was a way to run these loops in parallel in order to make the script more efficient?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use GNU parallel, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/GNU-Parallel.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
(   while x
    do
        loop 1
    done
) &
(   while y
    do
        loop 2
    done
) &
# Wait for both loops to finish
wait
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f1(){
while true ; do
    # do something
    sleep 1
done
}

f2(){
while true ; do
    # do something
    sleep 1
done
}

# run both f1 and f2 in parallel
f1 &
PID1=$!

f2 &
PID2=$!

# waits the end of both
wait $PID1 $PID2
echo "Done!"
```

Comment: You don't actually need to save the PIDs, or specify them after `wait` - you could just use `wait` with no parameters and it will wait for all background processes.

Comment: Hi Denio and Mark, would something like this work as well? `function loop1 { loop 1 }` `function loop2 { loop 2 }` `loop1 &` `loop2 &` wait

Comment: Are the while loops necessary?

Comment: The while loops are only examples. You can put any command inside functions to reflect your actual job.

Comment: Of course, you can wait for all background processes with `wait -`. However this can not be what do you want. :-)